# Java: Turning group of characters into single String

Tags: java, string, loops, char, character

I've been trying to make a program that will allow me to encrypt a username and password and print the result. I can get it to work, but I want to sort the characters that come out of the loop into a single String to make it easier to manage. Any advice?

```
System.out.println("\nYour encrypted username is " );

    for(char c : namech)
    {
        int temp = (int)c;
        int namecode = 0;

        //makes the characters w,x,y,z loops back to the start of the alphabet
        if(temp<=90 & temp>=65)
        {
            namecode = temp+4;

            if(namecode == 91)
            {
                namecode = 65;
            }
            else if(namecode == 92)
            {
                namecode = 66;
            }
            else if(namecode == 93)
            {
                namecode = 67;
            }
            else if(namecode == 94)
            {
                namecode = 68;
            }

            int i = namecode;

            char d = (char)i;


            System.out.print(d);



        }
```

Comment: Any reason you'd use the integers rather than using character literals in your source code? The latter would make life *much* simpler...

Comment: You can append a char to a string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use StringBuilder and append each character as you encrypt it. Simple and efficient concatenation. IE.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (char c : namech)
{
    // ... your code was here
    sb.append(d);
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to sort the characters that come out of the loop into a single String

The simplest approach is probably to turn the whole thing into a `char[]`, then convert that back to a string:

```
char[] chars = namech.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
    chars[i] = obfuscateCharacter(chars[i]);
}
String obfuscated = new String(chars);
```

... where `obfuscateCharacter` is basically the body of your current loop, but extracted into a method dealing with a single character, which is easier to test etc. (I refuse to call it `encryptCharacter` as that gives an impression of security :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = null;
int j = 91;
int k = 92;

result = String.valueOf((char)j);
result += String.valueOf((char)k);
```

Btw this looks like a perfect place to make use of a Switch statement instead of multiple if, else if....

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you really need encrypted data, it's hard to do yourself. In general, it's not a good idea to hand-roll your own encryption, and instead use a more trusted encryption scheme.

See the Bouncy Castle API, mentioned  in **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430412/what-java-library-should-i-use-for-cryptography**
http://www.bouncycastle.org/